# MongoDB Replicaset with two members, hot to prevent Primary from becoming secondary when secondary disconnects?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database

When using MongoDB with a replica set of 2 servers, if the secondary goes down, primary becomes secondary. I would like it to maintain it's primary state even if the secondary is down. apparently, since there are no other members in the set, the election process cannot give more than 50% votes to the primary to be the primary and it becomes secondary.

Answer (score 3):

That's why a replica-set with two active nodes should always include an [arbiter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-replica-set-arbiter/) on a separate server as a third member. An arbiter is a mongod instance which holds no data, but is allowed to vote in primary-elections.

When the secondary goes down, there will still be the arbiter to elect the remaining node to primary.

An arbiter is a very lightweight process, so it doesn't require a dedicated server. But for obvious reasons it shouldn't share the hardware with another member of the replica-set.

Answer (score 2):

I found this snippet on Mongodb site, that solves this issue easily, using the vote weights and Priority:
{
  _id : 'setName',
  members : [
    { _id : 0, host : "", priority : 1 },
    { _id : 1, host : "", priority : 0, votes : 0 }
  ]
}

I tried it , it works! i could shut down the secondary without affecting the primary.

Comment: While adjusting the votes "works" it defeats one of the key features of replica sets: your configuration does not enable automatic failover. If your primary goes down, your secondary will remain a secondary. A better approach would be to add an arbiter so either of your data-bearing nodes can be elected as a primary.

Comment: Thanks, Generally you are right, but in my case I'm using replication for different purpose than failover, we are doing the BI and analytics and reporting on the replica server to offload these tasks from the main one.

Answer (score 1):

Since a majority of the set is not online you cannot elect a new primary ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum ) or keep the current one there.

You must always have a majority of the set online otherwise you will need to: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

If I use my powers of mental rememberance I remember @Asya specifically stating this is because at the end of the day MongoDB cannot know if there is a network partition or that server is actually the last server there, as such without the majority of configured members up MongoDB just doesn't try and guess consistentcy.

It comes down the age old question, "if something is not pingable is it down?"